# user input - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code that I am working on , it is for ordering pizza. I have been coding for 7 days and I want to find out how can I make the pizza prices bigger by the size of the pizza
For example , small pizza is 15.75$ medium is 16.75 and big is 17.75

Each time I run the code , the output is 15.75

### (Look at the bottom portion)

---

```js
employee = confirm("Are you ready to take an order?");

if (employee === true) {
  console.log("Here is the order");
} else {
  console.log("Ask another employee to take the order. If there is no one, then please take the order ");
}

let orderCount = 0;
const takeOrder = (topping, crustType) => {
  orderCount++;
  console.log("Order: " + crustType + " pizza topped with " + topping);
};
//


// Order comes here like this - takeOrder('pepperoni', //'texas style');
takeOrder('pepperoni', 'texas style');
//

const getSubTotal = (itemCount) => {
  return itemCount * 14.5;
};
//const ^^
console.log("The Sub-Total is " + getSubTotal(orderCount) + "$");




const getTax = (itemCount) => {
  return itemCount * 1.25;
};

console.log("The tax is " + getTax(orderCount) + "$");

const getTotal = () => {
  return getSubTotal(orderCount) + getTax(orderCount);
};

console.log("And the final total is " + getTotal() + "$");


console.log("Thank you for taking this order.")
```

Comment: you didn't try anything to modify the prices, why should output something else?

Answer (score 0):

As for one of the comments, the price relative to size is not in your logic:

```
let priceBySize = {
    'S': 15.75,
    'M': 16.75,
    'L': 14.5,
}
// size of order required - might consider also to pass quantity
takeOrder('pepperoni', 'texas style', 'M');
takeOrder('margherita', 'clasic style', 'L');

const getSubTotal = (itemCount, size) => {
    return itemCount * priceBySize[size];
};
```

Also instead of fixed prices for size maybe you'll prefer to have multipliers for sizes and base price per type of pizza.